# What bind to use to detect FlatNotebook tab page closing vis FNB_X_ON_TAB

Tags: wxpython

I'm using wxPython FlatNotebook widget and have enabled the FNB_X_ON_TAB style. But what bind event triggers on this action (clicking the x in the tab to close it)?

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.flatnotebook as fnb


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "FlatNotebook Demo")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        notebook = fnb.FlatNotebook(panel, -1)
        self.Bind(fnb.EVT_FLATNOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSED, self.popup_close_tab, id=100)
        for i in range(3):
            caption = "Page %d" % (i + 1)
            notebook.AddPage(self.CreatePage(notebook, caption), caption)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
    
    def CreatePage(self, notebook, caption):
        '''
        Creates a simple :class:`Panel` containing a :class:`TextCtrl`.
        :param `notebook`: an instance of `FlatNotebook`;
        :param `caption`: a simple label.
        '''
        p = wx.Panel(notebook)
        wx.StaticText(p, -1, caption, (20, 20))
        wx.TextCtrl(p, -1, "", (20, 40), (150, -1))
        return p

    def popup_close_tab(self, event):
        print("popup_close_tab")
        #self.close_tab()

# our normal wxApp-derived class, as usual
app = wx.App(0)
frame = MyFrame(None)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Usually, the `X` on the Tab triggers `wx.EVT_CLOSE`.

Comment: Yeah, but in this case, for some reason I can't figure out, clicking on the tab x doesn't fire the event.

Comment: You'll have to post more code or create a minimal, reproducible example (reprex) https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Often this can enable you to solve the problem.

Comment: Post updated with working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forcing the widget `Id` in the `Bind` command, to be 100.
But nothing has been set to an Id of 100.
You have options:

- Set the notebooks Id to 100
- Leave the Id out of the Bind, assuming you have only 1 FlatNotebook
- Get the Id in the Bind
- Bind to the widget not self

So:

- `notebook = fnb.FlatNotebook(panel, 100)`
- `self.Bind(fnb.EVT_FLATNOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSED, self.popup_close_tab)`
- `self.Bind(fnb.EVT_FLATNOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSED, self.popup_close_tab, id=notebook.GetId())`
- `notebook.Bind(fnb.EVT_FLATNOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSED, self.popup_close_tab)`

It's a pretty flexible system, however serendipity had left the building, when you made one of the few choices, that wouldn't work. :)